# AddItem to shopping cart

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, shopping-cart

I'm building a webshop in C# (MVC). Now I want to change the number of items that is shown in the cart-icon (at the layout-page). I've found this code and want to customize it to my page.

```
$(function () {
    // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
    $("#@product.ArtNumber").click(function () {
        // Get the id from the link
        var itemToAdd = $(this).attr("data-id");
        if (itemToAdd != '') {
            // Perform the ajax post
            $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
                function (data) {
                    // Successful requests get here
                    // Update the page elements
                    if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                        $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                    } else {
                        $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                    }
                    $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                    $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Now I have a question about " $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart" "

In my case I don't want to switch to another page when you click the button - but add an item to the cart (at the layout-page). What can I write instead of "post"? As I've understand this is used when you want to open a new HTML-page?

Comment: This will simply post data to your controller action. It will not redirect to another page, unless you create a button that submits a form. The reason why is because you're using ajax. So when the '#@product.ArtNumber' button is clicked, you're going to pass the recordToDelete to your controller action. The page itself will have some elements updated based on the response from your controller. When you don't use ajax, the page would typically post to a different page.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if you believe it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $.post is shorthand of jQuery.post.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

It is an ajax call, and occurs in the background asynchronously.  You are expected to have an endpoint that will handle the HTTP post on the server.  Ideally this will update the server with the cart information such that it is available later if the client disconnects or closes their browser.

> In my case I don't want to switch to another page when you click the button

I failed to actually answer your question directly.  It will not take you to a different page or navigate away from the current page.  You can actually open a new tab and paste that URL into the browser and see that it returns JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your comment David! It made things clearer :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.  The answer I proposed has still not been marked as accepted though, do you still need help with something?  The answer would have a green check mark under the vote arrows if accepted.  Just let me know...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know :)